# React how can I fix stale state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is a simplified version of my code. What is a good solution to fix stale states?

Wanted behavior: focus input field -> dropdown appears (state is true) -> click button -> dropdown disappears (state is false)

Actual behavior: focus input field -> dropdown renders (state is true) -> click button -> dropdown disappears for 0.1 second (state is false) -> dropdown appears (state is true)

```
const DropdownSelector = () => {
  const [toggleEnabled, setToggleEnabled] = useState(false);

  const handleToggle = () => setToggleEnabled(!toggleEnabled);

  const handleFocus = () => setToggleEnabled(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={val} onFocus={handleFocus} />
      <button onClick={handleToggle}>
      {toggleEnabled && (
        <div>I'm a dropdown</div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This is incomplete code, you're missing the button's closing tag, and `val` is undefined. Please update question to include full and complete code, preferably a more reliable example that actually reproduces the issue you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a function to `setState` when new state depends of previous state and/or props

```
const handleToggle = () =>
  setToggleEnabled((previousToggle) => !previousToggle);
```

[resource](https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1)